# Find the total revenue , calculus

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, economics, riemann-sum

The Marginal Revenue of an Item sold is $ \ R(x)= 100 e^{-0.001 x} \ $ dollers .

Find the total revenue by selling items $ \ 101 \ $ through $ \ 1000 \ $.

**Answer:**

I think this would be the integral  $ \ \int_{101}^{1000} R(x) \ dx \ \ $

**But I am not sure** .

Help me

Comment: Your answer is right.

Comment: Why not from 100.5 to 1000.5?

Comment: or $\sum_{101}^{1000} R(x)$, which is an arithmetic series

Comment: @yourmath Have you solved this? Are you still interested in a solution?

Answer (score 3):

As the comments stated, this is a basic algebra problem. Nonetheless, it requires some attention to details.

As an arithmetic series, denote $\displaystyle S \equiv \sum_{x = 101}^{1000}R(x)~$, then
\begin{align*}
S = 100 \sum_{x = 101}^{1000} e^{\frac{-x}{1000}} &= 100 \,e^{\frac{-100}{1000}}\sum_{x = 1}^{900} e^{\frac{-x}{1000}} \\
&= 100 \,e^{\frac{-1}{10}} \frac{ e^{\frac{-1}{1000} } - e^{\frac{-901}{1000} } }{1 -  e^{\frac{-1}{1000}} }  \qquad \text{as}~ \sum_{x = 1}^{900} r^x = \frac{ r - r^{901} }{1 - r} \quad \text{where}~ r = e^{\frac{-1}{1000}}
\end{align*}
The numerical value is about $53669$, or with more digits, [$53668.95426225823\ldots$ as per Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=100+Exp%5B-0.1%5D+(Exp%5B-0.001%5D+-+Exp%5B-0.901%5D)%2F(1+-+Exp%5B-0.001%5D)) or any computing software.

Let's compare this with the following integral approximations, all courtesy of Wolfram Alpha:

Original poster's suggestion, [integration limits nominally match: $\displaystyle\int_{x = 101}^{1000}R(x) \approx 53605$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B100+Exp%5B-x%2F1000%5D,+%7Bx,+101,+1000%7D%5D)

Commented by @cgiovanardi: [standard first order correction 
 $\displaystyle\int_{x = 100.5}^{1000.5}R(x) \approx 53669$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B100+Exp%5B-x%2F1000%5D,+%7Bx,+100.5,+1000.5%7D%5D) , very close to the exact solution.

Just shift it for the sake of comparison [to the right: $\displaystyle\int_{x = 101}^{1001}R(x) \approx 53642$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B100+Exp%5B-x%2F1000%5D,+%7Bx,+101,+1001%7D%5D)

Shift for the sake of comparison [to the left: $\displaystyle\int_{x = 100}^{1000}R(x) \approx 53696$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B100+Exp%5B-x%2F1000%5D,+%7Bx,+100,+1000%7D%5D)